# Compare two columns data with different data type

Tags: mysql, database-design, datatypes

[image]

I would like to achieve how many invoices have two of the same product with different docline numbers.
Invoice and docline have numeric data type and product has char type.
So for instance invoice x has two of the same products with docline x and Y.
So far I havent found a luck how to compare to get value that I am expecting.

Comment: What have you tried? What were the results, and what did you expect?

Comment: *Compare two columns data with different data type ... Invoice and docline have numeric data type and product has char type.* Unclear. Do you want to compare `product` with `invoice` and/or `docline`?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please go to dbfiddle.uk and provide your table, some sample data and your desired result. Put that information back in the question! Images are discouraged here for the reasons outlined in [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530)!

Comment: Which two lines in your example are to be treated as "the same product"?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to achieve how many invoices have two of the same product with different docline numbers.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT invoice)
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 USING (invoice, product)
WHERE t1.docline > t2.docline
```

or

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT invoice)
FROM table t1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM table t2
               WHERE t1.invoice = t2.invoice
                 AND t1.product = t2.product
                 AND t1.docline > t2.docline )
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your taking time on providing solution. is your answer based on the fact that I have only one table and I would like to compare within the same table